# how to migrate magento dashboard settings?

Tags: magento

I have already installed magento in my localhost ,and its working fine.I have copied all the code from live to my localhost .But only thing is missing  the  magento dashboard settings which I had made on the live magento dashboard like the CMS pages ,some product attritbutes etc .How do i migrate these settings ?
I have copied  the earlier database of live site ,and I don't want to replace  localhost database with  live site database.but you can tell some specific tables .

```
<?php


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in live site you have made change in CMS pages, Product Attributes etc. So It will be good to import whole database instead of particular tables as importing particular table may create problem.